# how to "join" 2 web requests in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, asp.net-web-api

I try to merge data from 2 webApis. Something like that:

```
$http.get($scope.apiUrl1 + 'GetEmployees').success(function(data1) {
    //process data1
    $http.get($scope.apiUrl2 + 'GetEmployees2').success(function(data2) {
        //process data2
        var data = data1.join(data2);
    })
})
```

What I don't like on this solution is because apiUrl2 is called after the response on first request.

There is a way to call both api in the same time and to wait answer for both of them?
Promise can be a solution?

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: append both requests to some array and resolve it with `$q.all(promises)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularJS you can use $q.all(), where each $http request is a variable, like so:

```
let get1 = $http.get($scope.apiUrl1 + 'GetEmployees');
let get2 = $http.get($scope.apiUrl2 + 'GetEmployees2');

$q.all([get1, get2]).then(data => {
  console.log('the data: ', data);
});

//you can also pass in an object to $q.all, allowing you to refer to the promises by variable name rather than index

$q.all({get1, get2}).then(data => {
  console.log('the data: ', data);
});
```

Here's a nice comprehensive blog about $q and what it can do:

https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q

Comment: I really like that solution: $q.all({get1, get2}) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

use `$q.all`. First Inject the `$q` to the controller/

```
let arr = [$http.get($scope.apiUrl1 + 'GetEmployees'), $http.get($scope.apiUrl2 + 'GetEmployees2')]

$q.all(arr).then(function (response) {
        //process data2
        var data = response[0].data.concat(response[1].data);
})
```